# Connect to an AWS EC2 instance using MsTscLib

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, amazon-ami, mstsc

One of my dotnet application connects to RDP server to run business task using MsTscLib. Now that our server moving to AWS, it should do the same with an EC2 instance.

So far I am not able to connect to the RDP in AWS.

Anyone done this?

I am adding the code block

```vb
Friend WithEvents rdp As AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting

Dim secured As IMsTscNonScriptable = DirectCast(rdp.GetOcx(), IMsTscNonScriptable)

secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text

rdp.Connect()
```

I get no exception, but just the ActiveX does not connect to the instance. `rdp.Connected` property stays '0' meaning not connected.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  Are you able to RDP into the instance using mstsc or some other RDP client?

Comment: I could connect to the instance using `mstsc` command. But fail to connect through program with out any exception. I have added the code block in the question now.